# Search JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, search

I am attempting to parse and search my json file using jQuery, I am able to parse the json file but not search it.

My HTML

`<ol id="results"></ol>`

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('myJson.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $('<li />').html(item.name + '<br>' + item.details + '<br>').appendTo('#results');
        }
    });
});​
```

The above code returns all items, however I now wish to allow users to search the json file, so i include a form input and create an onclick event and pass the input to a search see link below.

The problem is the input variable isnt being passed to the seach?
Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/xpTk5/7/

---

UPDATE: Passing the variable to the Regex seems to be the problem.

---

Solved: `if (item.name.search(new RegExp(q, "i")) != -1){`

Thanks for your attempts and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I'm almost sure that `RegExp(/''+q+''/i)` does not do what you think.

Comment: @All In my edit I copied the code from his fiddle here after formatting it, but it was different from the original code posted. I have reverted the edit.

Comment: You are correct, however if i use `RegExp(/q/i)`, RegExp assumes that "q" is the string to match.

Comment: I think you'll find the library I've authored does what you want: http://www.json.spiritway.co

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the text box after the form is submitted. Where you had it, it would never be set since it gets the value when the document is ready (and probably before anything is input).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var q = $('#query').val();
        $.getJSON('myJson.json', function(data) {
            // iterator
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                // search the results using regular expression for the query
                if (item.name.search(new RegExp(/''+q+''/i)) != -1) {
                    $('<li />').html(item.name + '<br>' + item.details + '<br>').appendTo('#results');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks gpojd, however I tried your suggestion and the variable isn't being passed.

Comment: This worked in the fiddle that you posted (although it didn't make it much farther because of other issues).

Answer (score 0):

The variable was being read by the regex.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var q = $('#query').val();
    $.getJSON('myJson.json', function(data) {
        // iterator
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            // search the results using regular expression for the query
            if (item.name.search(new RegExp(q, "i")) != -1) {
                $('<li />').html(item.name + '<br>' + item.details + '<br>').appendTo('#results');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpTk5/8/